# Wordpress lê o logotipo só no localhost

Tags: wordpress

No site que eu fiz o logo funciona quando estou testando em casa com o localhost, mas, no site ele não lê.

```
<img id="logo_topo" class="img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/imagens/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
```

Quando inspeciono o elemento o src no modo localhost é:

```
src="http://localhost/site/wp-content/themes/site_tema/imagens/logo.png"
```

No site fica assim:

```
src="/site/wp-content/themes/site_tema/imagens/logo.png"
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: voce já trocou o siteurl no wp_options?

Comment: Já arrumei ali sim, está assim "http://site.com.br/" no campo siteurl e no campo home, não aparece o "h t t p : / /" aqui, mas está no db

Comment: Na verdade Pedro, o meu stylesheet esta com esse problema também, ele fica assim <link id="style_cor" rel="stylesheet" href="/site/wp-content/themes/site/style/padrao/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"> mas não lê

Comment: tenta colocar o caminho do stylesheet direto do servidor, como se fosse ficar assim `<link id="style_cor" rel="stylesheet" href="http://site.com/wp-content/themes/site/style/padrao/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">` ou voce pode tentar `<link id="style_cor" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/wp-content/themes/site/style/padrao/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">`

Comment: Cara por incrível que pareça, eu fiz isso e ele ainda corta o começo do endereço e deixa só "/site/wp-content/themes/site_tema/imagens/logo.png", mas eu vi que você falou do stylesheet, vou tentar e te falo

Comment: Faz a mesma coisa, ele corta o começo do endereço

Comment: Eu percebi que o endereço que ele gera "http://localhost/site/wp-content" na web deveria ficar "http://site.com.br/wp-content/", mas fica "http://site.com.br/site/wp-content/"

Comment: mas a pasta wp-content ta dentro de alguma pasta( `public_HTML/pasta-exemplo/wp-content`) no servidor ou ta na raiz( `public_HTML/wp-content`)?

Comment: isso, esta assim /public_html/site.com.br/wp-content

Comment: Olha isso, no footer estou puxando o js <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jsitei.js"></script>, e o endereço gerado é assim ''src="http://site.com.br/wp-content/themes/site/js/site.js"''

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46940/discussion-between-pedro-henrique-kuzminskas-and-ale-moraes).

Comment: O mesmo bloginfo('template_directory'), no style <link id="style_cor" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style/<?php echo $estilo_cor_variavel; ?>/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> gera isso: <link id="style_cor" rel="stylesheet" href="/site/wp-content/themes/site/style/padrao/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

Answer (score 0):

Troque a referência da pasta para `get_template_directory_uri()`

Ficará assim:

```
<img id="logo_topo" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/imagens/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
```

Comment: Fica do mesmo jeito cara.  /site/wp-content/themes/site/imagens/logo.png

Answer (score 0):

Tente deixar apenas assim:

```html
/wp-content/themes/site/imagens/logo.png
```

deixe apenas esse caminho e teste com CTRL + F5.

Aqui pra mim funcionou.